# QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'QObjectList'

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Ошибка: `QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'QObjectList' for property 'ViewshedGeoElement_QMLTYPE_43::PointLogLag'`

Я в main зарегистрировал :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qRegisterMetaType<QObjectList*>("QObjectLists*");
    ...
}
```

Файл класса ViewshedGeoElement (ViewshedGeoElement.h)

```
    #include <QObjectList>

    using namespace Esri::ArcGISRuntime;

    class ViewshedGeoElement : public QQuickItem
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        Q_PROPERTY(QObjectList PointLogLag READ PointLogLag NOTIFY PointLogLagChanged)
       ...
       public:
         static void init();
       private:
         QObjectList m_PointLogLag;
         QObjectList PointLogLag() const;    
     };
```

Файл класса ViewshedGeoElement (ViewshedGeoElement.cpp)

```
...
    void ViewshedGeoElement::init()
    {
       // Register classes for QML
       qmlRegisterType<SceneQuickView>("Esri.Samples", 1, 0, "SceneView");
       qmlRegisterType<ViewshedGeoElement>("Esri.Samples", 1, 0, "ViewshedGeoElementSample");
    }
    void ViewshedGeoElement::componentComplete()
    {
    ...
        connect(m_sceneView, &SceneQuickView::mouseClicked, this, [this](QMouseEvent& mouseEvent)
        {
          Point clickedPoint = m_sceneView->screenToBaseSurface(mouseEvent.x(), mouseEvent.y());

          m_PointLogLag.append(new Coordinates(clickedPoint.x(),clickedPoint.y()));
          emit PointLogLagChanged();
    //      points.append(clickedPoint);
        });
    }

    QObjectList ViewshedGeoElement::PointLogLag() const
    {
       return m_PointLogLag;
    }
```

файл класса Coordinates coordinates.h:

```
#ifndef COORDINATES_H
#define COORDINATES_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QVariant>

class Coordinates : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(double latitude READ latitude WRITE setLatitude NOTIFY latitudeChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(double longitude READ longitude WRITE setLongitude NOTIFY longitudeChanged)
public:
    Coordinates(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Coordinates(const Coordinates &other);
    Coordinates(double latitude,double longitude,QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void setLatitude(const double &latitude);
    void setLongitude(const double &longitude);
    double latitude() const;
    double longitude() const;
signals:
    void latitudeChanged();
    void longitudeChanged();
private:
    double m_latitude;
    double m_longitude;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Coordinates*)
#endif // COORDINATES_H
```

файл класса Coordinates coordinates.cpp :

```
#include "coordinates.h"

Coordinates::Coordinates(QObject *parent)
    :QObject{parent}
    ,m_latitude {0.0}
    ,m_longitude {0.0}
{

}
Coordinates::Coordinates(const Coordinates &other)
  :QObject{other.parent()}
  ,m_latitude {other.m_latitude}
  ,m_longitude {other.m_longitude}
{

}
Coordinates::Coordinates(double latitude,double longitude,QObject *parent)
    :QObject{parent}
    ,m_latitude {latitude}
    ,m_longitude {longitude}
{

}
void Coordinates::setLatitude(const double &latitude)
{
    if (m_latitude !=latitude)
    {
        m_latitude = latitude;
        emit latitudeChanged();
    }
}

void Coordinates::setLongitude(const double &longitude)
{
    if (m_longitude != longitude)
    {
        m_longitude = longitude;
        emit longitudeChanged();
    }
}

double Coordinates::latitude() const
{
    return m_latitude;
}
double Coordinates::longitude() const
{
    return m_longitude;
}
```

Comment: QObjectList* - а зачем указатель?

Comment: @Madisson Всё равно та же ошибка . Как передать QObjectList в QML?

Comment: qRegisterMetaType<QObjectList*>("QObjectLists*"); лишняя `s` (последняя) в строке аргумента

Comment: @Alexander Chernin  вы супер !!заработало